# react getElementById is null

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Download = () => {
    const desc = document.getElementById('description')

    useEffect(() => {
        desc.innerHTML = '<h1>Work</h1>' // desc is null, cannot set.
    }, [])

    return (
        <div id='descritpion'>

        </div>
    )
}


export default Download
```

Here I am getting a element by its id and am trying to set it's innerHTML, but for some reason it is null, I have never encountered this problem because last time I did something like this it worked... so I dont know what wrong, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for `description` but the actual div has id `descritpion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because by the time your component mounts, it has not rendered into a DOM yet. You can use `useLayoutEffect` to achieve this. I will show an example, but I think you shouldn't use vanilla javascript DOM manipulation, but use [React ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const Download = () => {
    const desc = document.getElementById('description')

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        desc.innerHTML = '<h1>Work</h1>' // desc is null, cannot set.
    }, [])

    return (
        <div id='description'>

        </div>
    )
}
```

### What I would do:

```
const Download = () => {
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState("Work")

    return (
        <div id='description'>
           {desc && <h1> {desc} </h1>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your code `<div id='descritpion'></div>` your id should be `description` not `descritpion`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Download = () => {
    const desc = document.getElementById('description')

    useEffect(() => {
        desc.innerHTML = '<h1>Work</h1>' // desc is null, cannot set.
    }, [])

    return (
        <div id='description'></div>
    )
}


export default Download
```

and also it will still not work since you are finding the element but it is not even rendered yet!

here `const desc = document.getElementById('description')` you are getting that element but your element is not even rendered yet

Answer (score 0):

I think your question stems from a lack of experience with React, so rather than answering it directly, here is a suggestion for how to implement what you want in a way that makes sense with React:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Download = () => {
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("Work")

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{description}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Download
```

Then use setDescription to change the description.

Answer (score 0):

Just currect 'description' Spelling and `document.getElementById('description')` use in 'useEffect'.

```
const Demo = () => {
useEffect(() => {
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = '<h1>Work</h1> '
}, [])

return (
    <div id='description'>
    </div>
)
```

};